# unable to pass values from session variable for making pdf using iText and Struts2

Tags: java, classcastexception, itextpdf

Here what I am trying to do is I have made some lists where I am fetching values and storing it in some particular lists and since I want to access those values in another method I am creating session variable and I am passing that values in session variable by setting key and accessing it in another method using get(key) which I am successful to do so.But now what I want is i want to make pdf in another method using values which are in lists. But I am unable to do so.Below is my code and please help me to pass values for making pdf.

```
package com.ca.actions;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.SessionMap;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware;

import com.ca.database.Database;
import com.ca.pojo.Event;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Preparable;

public class DataForGeneralReportsAction extends ActionSupport implements
        Preparable, SessionAware {
    private List<String> eventsGeneral = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String> companiesGeneral = new ArrayList<String>();
    private SessionMap<String, Object> sessionMapGeneral;
    List<String> eventIdList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> eventNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> eventVenueList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> eventTimeList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> companyNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> totalAmountList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> receivedAmountList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> balanceAmountList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> eventTdsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> paymentDateList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> chequeDdList = new ArrayList<String>();

    private String eventGeneral = null;
    private String companyGeneral = null;
    List<Event> dataForGeneralReports;

    public List<String> getEventIdList() {
        return eventIdList;
    }

    public void setEventIdList(List<String> eventIdList) {
        this.eventIdList = eventIdList;
    }

    public List<String> getEventNameList() {
        return eventNameList;
    }

    public void setEventNameList(List<String> eventNameList) {
        this.eventNameList = eventNameList;
    }

    public List<String> getEventVenueList() {
        return eventVenueList;
    }

    public void setEventVenueList(List<String> eventVenueList) {
        this.eventVenueList = eventVenueList;
    }

    public List<String> getEventTimeList() {
        return eventTimeList;
    }

    public void setEventTimeList(List<String> eventTimeList) {
        this.eventTimeList = eventTimeList;
    }

    public List<String> getCompanyNameList() {
        return companyNameList;
    }

    public void setCompanyNameList(List<String> companyNameList) {
        this.companyNameList = companyNameList;
    }

    public List<String> getTotalAmountList() {
        return totalAmountList;
    }

    public void setTotalAmountList(List<String> totalAmountList) {
        this.totalAmountList = totalAmountList;
    }

    public List<String> getReceivedAmountList() {
        return receivedAmountList;
    }

    public void setReceivedAmountList(List<String> receivedAmountList) {
        this.receivedAmountList = receivedAmountList;
    }

    public List<String> getBalanceAmountList() {
        return balanceAmountList;
    }

    public void setBalanceAmountList(List<String> balanceAmountList) {
        this.balanceAmountList = balanceAmountList;
    }

    public List<String> getEventTdsList() {
        return eventTdsList;
    }

    public void setEventTdsList(List<String> eventTdsList) {
        this.eventTdsList = eventTdsList;
    }

    public List<String> getPaymentDateList() {
        return paymentDateList;
    }

    public void setPaymentDateList(List<String> paymentDateList) {
        this.paymentDateList = paymentDateList;
    }

    public List<String> getChequeDdList() {
        return chequeDdList;
    }

    public void setChequeDdList(List<String> chequeDdList) {
        this.chequeDdList = chequeDdList;
    }

    public SessionMap<String, Object> getSessionMapGeneral() {
        return sessionMapGeneral;
    }

    public void setSessionMapGeneral(
            SessionMap<String, Object> sessionMapGeneral) {
        this.sessionMapGeneral = sessionMapGeneral;
    }

        public String getEventGeneral() {
        return eventGeneral;
    }

    public void setEventGeneral(String eventGeneral) {
        this.eventGeneral = eventGeneral;
    }

    public String getCompanyGeneral() {
        return companyGeneral;
    }

    public void setCompanyGeneral(String companyGeneral) {
        this.companyGeneral = companyGeneral;
    }

    public List<Event> getDataForGeneralReports() {
        return dataForGeneralReports;
    }

    public void setDataForGeneralReports(List<Event> dataForGeneralReports) {
        this.dataForGeneralReports = dataForGeneralReports;
    }

    public List<String> getEventsGeneral() {
        return eventsGeneral;
    }

    public void setEventsGeneral(List<String> eventsGeneral) {
        this.eventsGeneral = eventsGeneral;
    }

    public List<String> getCompaniesGeneral() {
        return companiesGeneral;
    }

    public void setCompaniesGeneral(List<String> companiesGeneral) {
        this.companiesGeneral = companiesGeneral;
    }

    public DataForGeneralReportsAction() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void prepare() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            con = new Database().Get_Connection();

            // load companies
            PreparedStatement ps = con
                    .prepareStatement("SELECT DISTINCT company_name FROM event");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                companiesGeneral.add(rs.getString("company_name"));
            }

            // load events
            ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT DISTINCT event_name FROM event");
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                eventsGeneral.add(rs.getString("event_name"));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            con.close();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {

        Connection con = null;
        try {
            con = new Database().Get_Connection();

            // load the table. The first time the table is loaded completely
            String sql = "SELECT EVENT_ID, EVENT_NAME, COMPANY_NAME,EVENT_VENUE,TOTAL_AMOUNT,RECEIVED_AMOUNT,EVENT_TDS,BALANCE_AMOUNT,CHEQUE_DD_NO,"
                    + "date_format(PAYMENT_DATE,'%d/%m/%Y') as dateAsPayment,EVENT_TIME "
                    + "FROM event";
            String where = "";

            // if instead this action has been called from the JSP page,
            // the result is filtered on event and company:
            if (eventGeneral != null && companyGeneral != null) {
                where = " WHERE event_name = ? AND company_name = ?";
            }

            // load companies
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql + where);
            if (where.length() > 0) {
                ps.setString(1, eventGeneral);
                ps.setString(2, companyGeneral);
            }
            dataForGeneralReports = new ArrayList<Event>();
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            int i, j = 0;
            while (rs.next()) {

                dataForGeneralReports.add(new Event(rs.getString("EVENT_ID"),
                        rs.getString("EVENT_NAME"), rs
                                .getString("COMPANY_NAME"), rs
                                .getString("EVENT_VENUE"), rs
                                .getString("EVENT_TIME"), rs
                                .getString("TOTAL_AMOUNT"), rs
                                .getString("RECEIVED_AMOUNT"), rs
                                .getString("CHEQUE_DD_NO"), rs
                                .getString("dateAsPayment"), rs
                                .getString("BALANCE_AMOUNT"), rs
                                .getString("EVENT_TDS")));

                eventIdList.add(rs.getString("EVENT_ID"));
                eventNameList.add(rs.getString("EVENT_NAME"));
                companyNameList.add(rs.getString("COMPANY_NAME"));
                eventVenueList.add(rs.getString("EVENT_VENUE"));
                eventTimeList.add(rs.getString("EVENT_TIME"));
                totalAmountList.add(rs.getString("TOTAL_AMOUNT"));
                receivedAmountList.add(rs.getString("RECEIVED_AMOUNT"));
                chequeDdList.add(rs.getString("CHEQUE_DD_NO"));
                paymentDateList.add(rs.getString("dateAsPayment"));
                eventTdsList.add(rs.getString("EVENT_TDS"));
                balanceAmountList.add(rs.getString("BALANCE_AMOUNT"));

            }
            sessionMapGeneral.put("eventIdPdf", eventIdList);
            sessionMapGeneral.put("eventNamePdf", eventNameList);
            sessionMapGeneral.put("companyNamePdf", companyNameList);
            sessionMapGeneral.put("eventVenuePdf", eventVenueList);
            sessionMapGeneral.put("eventTimePdf", eventTimeList);
            sessionMapGeneral.put("totalAmountPdf", totalAmountList);
            sessionMapGeneral.put("receivedAmountPdf",receivedAmountList);
            sessionMapGeneral.put("chequeDdPdf", chequeDdList);
            sessionMapGeneral.put("paymentDatePdf",paymentDateList);
            sessionMapGeneral.put("eventTdsPdf", eventTdsList);
            sessionMapGeneral.put("balanceAmountPdf", balanceAmountList);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            con.close();
        }

        return SUCCESS;

    }

    public String generatePdfGeneral() throws Exception {

        System.out.println(sessionMapGeneral.get("eventIdPdf"));
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
                new FileOutputStream("D:\\GeneralReports.pdf"));
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(11);
        table.setSpacingBefore(25);
        table.setWidthPercentage(100);
        table.setSpacingAfter(25);

        PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Event ID "));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(c1);

        c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Event Name "));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(c1);

        c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Event Time"));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(c1);

        c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Event Venue"));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(c1);
        c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Company Name"));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(c1);
        c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Total Amount"));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(c1);
        c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Received Amount"));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(c1);
        c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cheque/DD Number"));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(c1);
        c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Payment Date"));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(c1);
        c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Event TDS"));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(c1);
        c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Balance Amount"));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(c1);

        table.setHeaderRows(1);
        table.addCell( (PdfPCell) sessionMapGeneral.get("eventIdPdf"));
        table.addCell("1");
        table.addCell("Net Amount");
        table.addCell("1");
        table.addCell("Service Tax Number: ");
        table.addCell("2");
        table.addCell("Service Tax @ 0.14 %");
        table.addCell("12jh");
        table.addCell("123");
        table.addCell("safs");
        table.addCell("Sbc Tax @0.50%");

        document.open();
        document.add(table);
        document.close();
        return "success";

    }

    @Override
    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> map) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sessionMapGeneral = (SessionMap) map;
    }

}
```

and I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell
    com.ca.actions.DataForGeneralReportsAction.generatePdfGeneral(DataForGeneralReportsAction.java:346)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:870)
    ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1293)
    ognl.ObjectMethodAccessor.callMethod(ObjectMethodAccessor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethodWithDebugInfo(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:117)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethod(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:108)
    ognl.OgnlRuntime.callMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1369)
    ognl.ASTMethod.getValueBody(ASTMethod.java:90)
    ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
    ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
    ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:494)
    ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:458)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
table.addCell( (PdfPCell) sessionMapGeneral.get("eventIdPdf"));
```

You have a `SessionMap` with `String` values as key and `Object` values as values:

```
private SessionMap<String, Object> sessionMapGeneral;
```

You add an entry with key `"eventIdPdf"`:

```
sessionMapGeneral.put("eventIdPdf", eventIdList);
```

The `eventIdList` is an `ArrayList`:

```
List<String> eventIdList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

You can't cast an `ArrayList` to a `PdfPCell` which is what you're trying to do here:

```
table.addCell( (PdfPCell) sessionMapGeneral.get("eventIdPdf"));
```

You have to do something like:

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
List<String> list = (List<String>) sessionMapGeneral.get("eventIdPdf");
for (String item : list) {
    cell.addElement(new Paragraph(item));
}
table.addCell(cell);
```

Comment: I have added this code table.setHeaderRows(1);
  PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
  List list1 =  (List<String>) sessionMapGeneral.get("eventIdPdf");
  for (String item : list1) {
      cell.addElement(new Paragraph(item));
  }
  table.addCell(cell);
  table.addCell("1"); and it shows red line on list1 in for each loop. it says cannot convert from object type to string

Comment: use . toString() method  to convert Object into  String

Comment: where should i write that because it is not allowing to write in for(String item: list1.toString())

Comment: I solved my problem . earlier it was List list=(List<String>)sessionMapGeneral.get("eventIdPdf"); which i changed to List<String> list=(List<String>)sessionMapGeneral.get("eventIdPdf");